# How do lambda expressions that are java function literals work?

Tags: java, lambda

In Programming Puzzles & Code Golf there's [this](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/4726/30353) meta question with this code:

```
interface I {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello");
  }
    String foo(String s);
  }
class C {
  I i = s -> s.substring(1);
}
```

This is a runnable program. I've been playing around with the code in ideone and was able to create all sorts of errors, but this strikes out to me as the most bizarre.

If you replace `s.substring(1)` with something like `5` you get this error:

```
Main.java:16: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression
I i = s -> 5;//s.substring(1);
           ^
int cannot be converted to String
```

Why is that? I don't see the lambda exactly implementing the interface after all.

Comment: Have you looked up any part of the error message: _`I` is not a **functional interface**?_

Comment: `class C` creates an implementation of `I` using a lambda, which you can only do for a functional interface.  When you removed the definition of the only non-static function `foo`, interface `I` is no longer a functional interface

Answer (score 3):

A lambda expression can only be assigned to a functional interface. A functional interface must have a single abstract method.

`foo` is the single abstract method of your `I` interface, so after you remove it, you can't assign a lambda expression to a variable of type `I`.

In addition, `foo` has a signature and return type matching the lambda expression `s -> s.substring(1)` - a single `String` argument and a `String` return type.

As for your edit - `I i = s -> 5;` is wrong, since the lambda expression has to implement the `I` interface, so it can't return an `int`, since the `foo` method of `I` returns a `String`.

Comment: OKAY. Clearly the functional interface error was an oversight of mine. I looked at it and thought `String foo(double a);` was inside the public static void portion. Anyway, I was more concerned with why modifying the lambda expression causes an error. For example if you change `s.substring(1)` to `5` you get `int cannot be converted to String`. What's up with that?

Comment: @Luminous Your `I` interface's `foo` method has a String return type, so the lambda expression must return a String, not an int, in order to be assigned to a variable of type `I`.

Comment: Why would `foo` care about the lambda at all? You're not exactly implementing the interface after all. Btw I'm changing my question because that functional interface error I have doesn't even relate to what I'm trying to get at.

Comment: @Luminous When you assign a lambda expression to a functional interface variable, the lambda expression implements that interface.

Comment: Oh. That's a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda expressions in Java 8 rely on interfaces which represent a function. These are called "functional interfaces". They are recognized by having a single abstract method.

If they have more than one, Java cannot tell which one the implementationg given by the lambda expression is supposed to imlement.

And of course, if there are none - Java cannot implement it because it does not exist.